# Python PyPDF - getting additional spaces when reading text using ExtractText

Tags: python, pdf, spaces, pypdf, extract-text-plugin

I'm trying to extract text from a PDF file that has Address information, shown as below

CALIFORNIA EYE SPECIALISTS MED GRP INC
1900 W GARVEY AVE S # 335
WEST COVINA CA 91790

and I'm using below logic to extract the data

```
f = open(addressPath.pdf,'rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
first_page = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
mytext = first_page.extractText().split('\n')
```

but I'm getting below output, logic is introducing additional spaces.
Any Idea, why this is happening?

C A L I F O RN IA E YE  SP E C I A L I STS M ED GRP INC
19 00 W G A R V EY A VE S # 3 35
WE S T CO VI NA  C A 91 7 90

Comment: I've just released a new version of PyPDF2 which improved text extraction a lot. Could you update and check if that solves your issue?

Answer (score 0):

PyPDF2 was handling spaces not at all for a long time. In April 2022, I improved the situation with a very simple logic. It was too simple and got many cases wrong.

The contributor pubpub-zz changed that. Today, version 2.1.0 was released which improves spacing a lot.